# Commenting printf() statements in code

Tags: c, coding-style, comments

Recently, working with a significant amount of code, I observed that sometimes adding some extra printf() statements and commenting them is very useful for debugging in later stages (makes it easier) when the code has to be modified. But there are debates about over-commenting the code and absence of proper comments. I am not sure where this practice stands? Also, a drawback I find in such a way of commenting is that it makes the code look uglier. Here's an example :

```
 ...... //code
 ...... 
 pkt_bytes_decd = avcodec_decode_audio4( aCodecContext, pFrame, 
                                         &frame_fin, &packet );

 //printf("%d bytes from packet decoded\n",pkt_bytes_decd);
 ...... 
 ...... //code
```

Is it a bad practice ? Can someone discuss the pros and cons from their experience ?

Comment: When I later add code to the above code, and if i have bugs in the newly added code, I can uncomment the above printf() statement and see where the problem lies. This practice has been helping me quite well.

Comment: You don't have a debugger?

Comment: I was expecting this question. I use Kdbg as frontend (with gdb as backend). But for a multi-threaded program, it's not working as expected. I tried using Helgrind (with valkyrie), but no success. I found this method of debugging a little easier(in certain cases) than using buggy debuggers.

Comment: yeah there is no silver bullet, in some cases I also use logging statements but try to have it as more permanent code. e.g. logging statement that can be turned off (regardless of release/debug)

Comment: Thanks for the positive advice. Can you elaborate the statement? I didn't understand it quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much cleaner to use some macro that depends on debugging flag being enabled or disabled.

This way, you do not need to uncomment anything to debug. Simply enable debug flag, and it immediately enables logging in all such places.

Sometimes another approach is used - function like `log(level, message)` is called, and it will emit message only if level is above set threshold (typically called error, warning, info, etc). It is not as efficient, but makes debugging much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you possibly give small examples in both the cases?

Comment: For first example, see [Android ALOGV_IF](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/include/cutils/log.h#L87) - it would be compliled out if `LOG_NDEBUG` exists. For second example, see [Android ALOGW](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/include/cutils/log.h#L128).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include the debugging statements in final code, then use a command-line option to set a global, and then check that global for each printf:

`if(DEBUG) printf("extra info");`

If you want the debugging statements, but not in final code, use the preprocessor:

```
$ gcc -DDEBUG <files>

#ifdef DEBUG
printf("extra info");
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks pretty simple. But wherever I have printf() statements that are necessary for logging, I have to add 2 more lines of code. Also, it makes the code look uglier. What do you think ?

Comment: Depending on your development environment, I might use a tool like [this](http://lifehacker.com/5611210/how-to-use-text-expansion-to-save-yourself-hours-of-typing-every-day) to make the debugging lines easier to type. I personally don't think it's very hard to read, either, but that is more of a personal matter.I've found this method worth the extra effort myself, but I am more of a hobbyist than a professional, so I can't say it's the industry standard or anything, but it works well for me.

Comment: Point noted :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between permanently logging information for troubleshooting at customer site and just logging information when you are developing. I find the latter can mostly be replaced by using the debugger and with normal `// "why-comments"`. If it is too cumbersome to use the debugger for whatever reason then I personally find it better to have a logging mechanism that is not affected from whether it is release or debug mode.

There is always a risk with having two different versions of the program when you are developing, the release version and the debug version. If the versions differ too much you may get some nasty surprises later. In fact they are like two different programs.

For instance debugging statements generally make the program run slower so if you have some timing problem (e.g. race conditions) in your code they may become hidden but of course suddenly pop out when you are running the program in release mode (or more likely when you are showing the program to a customer/user).

### why-comment

++sp; // move the stack pointer beyond last element to mark underflow

### what-comment

++sp; // increment sp

Answer (score 0):

Compiler doesn't retain comments. So Its ok to write printf in comments.
Not a Bad Practice.. But overdoing it is bad.
Key to it is :-  **"balance"**

PROS :-
1) To debug for a quick check becomes lil easy.

CONS :-
1) Comments themselves can be more confusing then code.
2) While debugging ,Programmer may tend to be highly dependent on comments thus ignoring Code Flow.
3) Commenting while writing code is multi tasking. And thats slows down coding.:-(